# CakePHP HABTM data not saving to database

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a model `GenForm` which has a HABTM relationship with another model `PdfFile`. I use this to generate a list of checkboxes in my `GenForm` index view. In the `GenForm` model, I added:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'PdfFile' => array(
        'className' => 'PdfFile',
        'joinTable' => 'gen_forms_x_pdf_files'
    )
```

Here's a fragment from my `GenForm` `index.ctp` view:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input( 'PdfFile', array('label' => 'Select some PDF files', 'multiple' => 'checkbox') );
echo $this->Form->input( 'first_name' );
echo $this->Form->input( 'last_name' );
?>
```

In the controller, I have a basic save:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) { // form was submitted
        $this->GenForm->create();
        if ($this->GenForm->save($this->request->data)) {
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'generate', $this->GenForm->id)); // assemble the PDF for this record
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Log entry not saved.'));
        }
    }
```

Now `$this->data` looks something like this when I `debug()` it:

```
array(
    'PdfFile' => array(
        'PdfFile' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '5'
        )
    ),
    'GenForm' => array(
        'first_name' => 'xxx',
        'last_name' => 'xxx',
        'association_id' => '1',
        'email' => ''
    )
)
```

---

Everything works perfectly, but I couldn't validate the checkboxes (at least one must be checked). So, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418652/901048), I made some changes.

The `index.ctp` view became:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input( 'GenForm.PdfFile', array('label' => 'Select some PDF files', 'multiple' => 'checkbox') );
echo $this->Form->input( 'first_name' );
echo $this->Form->input( 'last_name' );
?>
```

Here's my validation rule:

```
public $validate = array(
    'PdfFile' => array(
        'rule' => array(
            'multiple', array('min' => 1)
        ), 
        'message' => 'Please select one or more PDFs'
    )
)
```

This is what `$this->data` looks like now:

```
array(
    'GenForm' => array(
        'PdfFile' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '5'
        ),
        'first_name' => 'xxx',
        'last_name' => 'xxx',
        'association_id' => '1',
        'email' => ''
    )
)
```

Now the checkboxes for `PdfFile` validate, but the `PdfFile` data isn't saved -- although the other fields for `GenForm` are saved correctly to their own table.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing so that `PdfFile` saves automatically *and* gets validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The first form is right

Stating the obvious, but the form that worked is the form to use i.e.:

```
echo $this->Form->input('PdfFile', array(
    'label' => 'Select some PDF files', 
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
));
```

Changing the form to have a "field" named 'PdfFile' will simply not work - as the model layer will remove any data for fields that don't exist - and in this form it will check for `gen_forms.PdfFile`, find there is no field and ignore the data.

### Validation

To take care of validation errors - use a validation rule running on the model which checks the number of habtm records to be saved. It doesn't matter what the name of the field used for validation is e.g.:

```
<?php
class GenForm extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'dummy' => array( // <- name this whatever you like
            'atLeastOne' => array(
                'required' => true, // run always
                'rule' => array('validateAtLeastOne')
            )
        )
    );

    function validateAtLeastOne() {
        if (!isset($this->data['PdfFile'])) {
            // there is no pdf data at all, ignore this rule
            // allow other save operations to work
            return true;
        }

        $return = count(array_filter($this->data['PdfFile']['PdfFile']));
        if (!$return) {
            $this->PdfFile->invalidate('PdfFile', 'Please upload a file');
        }
        return $return;
    }

}
```

Because the validation rule returns false if there are no records it will halt the save. By calling invalidate on the HABTM association with the same "field" name that the form helper will look for - an error message will be displayed.

### Alternatively

You can use the second approach in the question:

```
echo $this->Form->input('GenForm.PdfFile', array(
    'label' => 'Select some PDF files', 
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
));
```

In the full knowledge that this is *not* how cake expects to receive data and then manipulate it to be the right format in beforeValidate:

```
<?php
class GenForm extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'PdfFile' => array( // existing rule
            ...
        )
    );

    function beforeValidate() {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['PdfFile'])) {
            // keep the existing data as that's what validation will check against
            // copy to the right location so Cake will process it
            $this->data['PdfFile']['PdfFile'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['PdfFile'];
        }
        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I originally had a validation rule based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2044739/901048), but it seemed kludgey and inelegant to me.

Comment: k - then choose between "works but kludgey" and "doesn't work at all" =)

Comment: But shouldn't there be a way to force `PdfFile` to save based on the second arrangement?

Comment: quite simply no. the second arrangement is not defining a habtm relationship - it's defining a field in `GenForm` named `PdfFile` which doesn't exist and therefore doesn't do anything. That said, if you prefer you can use that and use beforeValidate to copy `GenForm.PdfFile` to `PdfFile.PdfFile` so that it works.

Comment: I thought maybe I could extract `PdfFile` from the `GenForm` array in `$this->data` and pass it manually to `$this->GenForm->PdfFile->save()`, but that was equally kludgey and inelegant.

Comment: Adding validation rules to my `PdfFile` object didn't work either -- they were marked as required in the view, but the actual validation wasn't triggered during the save.

Comment: I haven't said to add validation to your `PdfFile` model =) (that won't do anything - you are not saving PdfFile records - unless I completely misread the question). I've updated the answer with the permutation of the second approach that works.

Comment: Last question: Can you explain this quote [from the docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_validates)? "validates( ) - public - 
Returns true if all fields pass validation. Will validate hasAndBelongsToMany associations that use the 'with' key as well. Since _saveMulti is incapable of exiting a save operation."

Comment: @Blazemonger if you use `with` that means there is a bespoke join model; like Users <- Membership (habtm, table has more a primary key and more than 2 fields) -> Team. It's saying it will validate the Membership model - that's not relevant to your original question =).

Comment: Ok -- I think I'm content with how this works now. Perhaps once I know what I'm doing, I'll suggest it for an improvement to the code base.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, from [cake manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) probably you are formatting the data wrongly.

Try that `$this->data` looks like this:

```
array(
    'GenForm' => array(
        'first_name' => 'xxx',
        'last_name' => 'xxx',
        'association_id' => '1',
        'email' => ''
    ),
    'PdfFile' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '5'
    ),
)
```