# Issue with saving HABTM data in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, models, has-and-belongs-to-many

I’m having an issue saving HABTM data in a controller.

I have an `Article` model, which is associated to an `Event` model, as articles may be about specific events in my application. I’ve read the CakePHP cookbook entry on [saving HABTM data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) so understand how it works on the controller level, but having difficulties understanding how it should look on the view side of things.

What I have in my form are inputs for the article data (title, excerpt, content etc). I then want checkboxes for each event in my database then I can then check to associate an article with the corresponding event(s).

Normally, I would have a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="1" />
```

Where `1` is the ID of a venue, and do a checkbox like this for every event in my database, but this doesn’t seem to work in CakePHP.

What should I put for my field name when creating checkboxes with `$this->Form->input()`? What’s the “CakePHP” way?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about your form? Maybe you should provide your form view.

Comment: I have an array of all events in my database. I want to generate a checkbox for each event so that I can save the HABTM relation when I submit the form, but I don’t know what format CakePHP is expecting I put for the field name in my `$this->Form->input()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've set the events in the controller as described in the [Cook Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm):

```
$this->set('events', $this->Event->find('list'));
```

then your input should look like this, basically like the example in the Cook Book, with the addition of the [`multiple` option](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select) with an value of `checkbox`:

```
$this->Form->input('Event', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

This should give you a correctly formatted list of checkboxes with the events `displayField` as labels.

Your next problem might be validation, so also have a look at [CakePHP HABTM data not saving to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447275/cakephp-habtm-data-not-saving-to-database)

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. Turns out I need the `name` attribute set to `data[Event][Event][]` on my `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you save your data from the `ArticlesController::add()`.

So your view, you should have something like the following

**add.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Article');
echo $this->Form->input('Article.title', array('type' => 'text'));
echo $this->Form->input('Article.excerpt', array('type' => 'textarea'));
echo $this->Form->input('Article.title', array('type' => 'textarea'));

/** Generate multiple checkboxes, assumung that your array of events is $events **/
foreach($events as $index => $evt) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Event'.$index.'.id', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'value' => $evt['Event']['id']));
}
echo $this->Form->submit('save');
?>
```

The `foreach` loop will create a set of checkboxes which looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Event][0][id] value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Event][1][id] value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Event][2][id] value="3">
...
```

The respected data sent to the controller can be accessed via the `$this->request->data['Event']` array. If you have setup the relations correclty then the data saving
is been done automatically for you.

I hope this helps.