# hasMany + HABTM form validation in CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp

I have a posts table linked with a students table in a hasMany relation. 
And the students table is linked with a subjects table in a hasAndBelongsToMany relation:

`posts hasMany students`
`students HABTM subjects`

There is a form submitted from PostController. The form has several fields (multiple checkbox) for students to choose their subjects respectively:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Student.0.Subject'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Student.1.Subject'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Student.2.Subject'); ?>
```

I need to make sure every student chooses at least one subject, but Cake validation does not work like it should. I tried tweaking [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044102/habtm-form-validation-in-cakephp) to my needs, but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure where I'm doing it wrong?

```
function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    $test = Router::getParams();
    if ($test['pass'][0] == '3') {
    //check the field only if it's in step 3
        if (empty($this->data['Student'][0]['Subject'])) {
            $this->invalidate('non_existent_field'); // fake validation error
            $this->invalidate('Student.0.Subject', 'Please select at least one subject');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

fyi `$this->request->data['Student'][0]['Subject']` does return empty '' string..

EDIT:

$this->invalidate doesn't seem to work. I debug it and it returns `null`.